# drupal 7 redirect on session time out

Tags: php, session, drupal, drupal-7

I am new to Drupal.
Currently, The user is not redirected automatically to login page once the session gets expired instead it redirects only if I reload the page.
Is there any way to automate this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be an interesting option for you, the following module will show you an automate popup when the session is going to expired, then user can choose if want to close its session or wants to continue logged. If the user choose to close its session, it will be redirect to the login page. And if the user doesn't choose any option, it will automatically redirect to the login page.
[image]

[image]

https://www.drupal.org/project/autologout